# Open Firefox in Selenium for Python w/ Windows 10

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, windows-10

I'm trying to follow along with this tutorial

http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/ch01.html#_obey_the_testing_goat_do_nothing_until_you_have_a_test

which has me code the following to open a firefox browser using Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://localhost:8000')

assert 'Django' in browser.title
```

However, firefox opens to an annoying Windows 10 'welcome' page, and never visits the url I specify.  How do I get around this?

Comment: Is the dev server running at the moment?

Comment: Which selenium and firefox versions are you using? Also, any errors on the console?

Comment: @alecxe   firefox v 43.0.3, selenium v 2.47.1

Comment: Ok, a quick guess, upgrade selenium and try again: `pip install --upgrade selenium`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox 43 and selenium 2.47 have *compatibility issues*.

Upgrade `selenium` to the latest (currently, 2.48) version:

```
pip install --upgrade selenium
```